# How to stringify JSON using JQ

Tags: json, jq, datadog

Using JQ I would like to take a complex JSON object that includes JSON embedded as strings and then turn it all into a valid string I can easily embed in other JSON objects.

For example, lets say I have this json object:

```
{
  "region": "CA",
  "waf_rule_tags": "{\"RULEID:942100\":[\"application-multi\",\"language-multi\",\"platform-multi\",\"attack-sqli\",\"OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION\",\"WASCTC/WASC-19\",\"OWASP_TOP_10/A1\",\"OWASP_AppSensor/CIE1\",\"PCI/6.5.2\"]}"
}
```

I need to turn this all into the following string:

```
"{\"region\": \"CA\",\"waf_rule_tags\": \"{\\\"RULEID:942100\\\":[\\\"application-multi\\\",\\\"language-multi\\\",\\\"platform-multi\\\",\\\"attack-sqli\\\",\\\"OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION\\\",\\\"WASCTC/WASC-19\\\",\\\"OWASP_TOP_10/A1\\\",\\\"OWASP_AppSensor/CIE1\\\",\\\"PCI/6.5.2\\\"]}\"}"
```

That way I can take this string and insert it exactly under the `text` field of another JSON object to create the following.

```
{
      "title": "12345-accesslogs",
      "text": "{\"region\": \"CA\",\"waf_rule_tags\": \"{\\\"RULEID:942100\\\":[\\\"application-multi\\\",\\\"language-multi\\\",\\\"platform-multi\\\",\\\"attack-sqli\\\",\\\"OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION\\\",\\\"WASCTC/WASC-19\\\",\\\"OWASP_TOP_10/A1\\\",\\\"OWASP_AppSensor/CIE1\\\",\\\"PCI/6.5.2\\\"]}\"}",
      "priority": "normal",
      "tags": ["environment:test"],
      "alert_type": "info"
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In brief, `tostring` is your friend.

Assuming that your original JSON object is in a file named object.json, and that the template is in template.json, you could write:

```
jq --argfile object object.json '.text = ($object | tostring)' template.json
```

Needless to say, there are numerous variations on this theme, e.g.

```
jq -n 'input | input + {text: tostring}' \
   object.json template.json
```

or more compactly if slightly more obscurely:

```
jq 'input + {text: tostring}' object.json template.json
```

Comment: Yep  `jq '.| tostring' my_file.json` was what I was looking for.

Comment: You can simply write: `jq tostring my_file.json` :-)

Answer (score 9):

I found @peak's comment in their own answer so useful I wanted to make it an answer on its own:

```
$ echo '{ "foo": [ "bar", "baz" ] }' | jq -r tostring
{\"foo\":[\"bar\",\"baz\"]}
```

Answer (score 4):

JQ provides `tojson` and `fromjson` filters for that.

Note about the answers proposing `tostring`: The JQ manual says about `tojson`:

> The `tojson` builtin differs from `tostring` in that  `tostring`  returns  strings  unmodified,  while  `tojson`  encodes strings as JSON strings.

So I think `tojson` is always correct but `tostring` is only correct as long as you **only** use **complex** objects.

Answer (score 1):

A variation on this is to stringify a given key within a JSON structure using [`tostring`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#tostring)  something like this:

```sh
echo '{"a":1,"b":{"c":{"d":2},"e":3}}' | jq '.b.c=(.b.c|tostring)'
```

...which targets path `b.c` to give:

```json
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": {
    "c": "{\"d\":2}",
    "e": 3
  }
}
```

(As per A.H.'s answer, `tojson` might be useful instead of `tostring` if you want strings to be json-string-encoded as well)